# Starting Appium using command line in Mac Machine

Tags: automated-tests, appium, appium-ios

I was wondering if I can start appium in terminal of Mac machine similar to windows which is as under

```
appium -a <Machine IP> -p <port> -U <UDID>
```

1. Is there any similar command for iOS, as Mac terminal does not recognize `appium` as command

Please help me with this, I am very new to iOS

**PS**: I want to run web test on safari in iPad connected to Mac machine through Eclipse on Windows machine

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you may want to read how to start appium server programatically. Few links :  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/startstop-appium-server-programmatically-using-java-hassan-radi ; https://discuss.appium.io/t/starting-appium-server-programmatically-on-mac/1615 ; https://discuss.appium.io/t/launching-and-stopping-appium-server-programmtically/700

Comment: Refer these links on how to setup and how to start appium via java code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562142/how-to-start-appium-sever-from-the-java-code-in-eclipse/35569800#35569800  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35943901/appium-setup-no-reset-sh-file/35987045#35987045

Comment: Seems like your appium is not configured properly. It should run appium server on 4723 when you just type appium on terminal. It works for me.

Comment: This command worked for me when I installed appium again using `npm`, so is it something like if I install gui version of appium in mac I have to launch it from gui only?